# Cómo mostrar un mensaje debajo de un botón de enviar? en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo la siguiente duda, queriendo poner un FlutterToast debajo de un botón de "Enviar", para en todo momento siempre aparezca en el mismo lugar (por debajo del botón) el mensaje, sin importar el Responsive del tamaño de la pantalla, porque cuando pongo las propiedades, no tiene muchas variantes, es BOTTON, CENTER... alguna idea? gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask]